# Как расположить элемент в 20 px от нижней границы viewporta?

Tags: html, css

Как расположить элемент в 20 px от нижней границы viewporta? и центрировать его по горизонтали?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.biohazard {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 170px;
  left: 23px;
}

.yin-yang {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 135px;
}

.man-and-woman {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 180px;
  left: 250px;
}

.no-smoking {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.model {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 101;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.top {
  background-image: url(images/to-top.png);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Position Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a name="#top"></a>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="biohazard" src="images/biohazard.png" alt="biohazard">
    <img class="yin-yang" src="images/yin-yang.png" alt="yin-yang">
    <img class="man-and-woman" src="images/man-and-woman.png" alt="man-and-woman">
    <img class="no-smoking" src="images/no-smoking.png" alt="no-smoking">
  </div>
  <div class="model">
    <p>Здесь может быть Ваша реклама!!!</p>
  </div>
  <a class="top" href="#top"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Пример проблемы надо. Так не понятно. Что имеется ввиду под вьюпортом? Видимая часть страницы? Короче, лучше код дать, так не ясно.

Comment: якорь должен быть в 20px от нижней границы viewport’a и центрирован по горизонтали https://codepen.io/nvanyukova/pen/PoNKBeM?editors=1000

Comment: @NadyaWilde примеры кода лучше цеплять через сниппеты прямо в вопрос

Comment: Хорошо, кинула)

Comment: @NadyaWilde не совсем то что нужно, лучше так оформлять (см. правку). Какой элемент нужно центрировать? yin-yang?

Comment: .top. стрелочку эту.  Не понятно еще что такое 20 px от нижней границы вьюпорта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `position: fixed` - элемент будет прижат к нижней части вьюпорта, даже при скролле.

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.elem {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

---

Вариант с `position: absolute` - элемент будет на высоте вьюпорта - 20px.

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.elem {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100vh - 20px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, поняла!

Comment: @NadyaWilde, не за что. Если мой ответ вам помог, то отметьте его галочкой как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

```
.someElement {
  position: absolute /* или fixed, если надо, чтобы не уезжал при скроллинге */;
  top: 100vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-20px - 100%));
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!